# access to Servlet backend's ip address from a physical device (not from emulator)

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, android-studio, httprequest, android-networking

I added a Java app engine servlet backend to my app, and in my "client" I have a ServletPostAsyncTask class performing an http request to my backend.

If I use an emulator, I can access my backend through the IP address 10.0.2.2:8080, but if I run on a physical device, I receive the "http://10.0.2.2:8080 connection refused" error.

Now, I can't use localhost or 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.2.2 because with localhost I would be trying to connect to my own smartphone, and  10.0.2.2 is the Special alias to my host loopback interface and is therefore suitable for use only from an emulator. But then, isn't there any alias address created to point to my development machine from a physical device?

I just can't wrap my head around it.

This is my code. Class ServletPostAsyncTask in "client" performing the HTTP request:

```
class ServletPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {
private Context context;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
    context = params[0].first;
    String name = params[0].second;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://myIPaddress:8080/hello");
    // http://10.0.2.2:8080 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
        try {
        // Add name data to request
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
            return "Error: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

       Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

As a consequence to this issue, when I run on any of the mentioned addresses I get this error: 
"http://myIPaddress:8080 connection refused"

- I already have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in my manifest file
- I know that 10.0.2.2 is the equivalent of 127.0.0.1 when I use the emulator, but I'm not trying to run from an emulator, I'm trying to run on a physical device. In fact this code works within my emulator but doesn't within my physical device.

Why isn't there a similar alias to use from physical devices? If there isn't, then what my IP address should be?

Comment: Are you sending the servlet a post request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Application and Java server issue. Connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067113/android-application-and-java-server-issue-connection-refused)

Comment: I am sorry probably I wasn't clear enough, but my question is not a duplicate. In fact, what I'm trying to find an answer for is accessing my development machine (the backend) from a physical device, not from an emulator.

Therefore the answers provided in the supposedly duplicated question do not apply to my case, as the IP address 10.0.2.2 is an alias to the host loopback interface, also addressing the development machine,  but only from an emulator.
What I need is an equivalent of 10.0.2.2 suitable for use from my phone, a NAT-ed IP address pointing to the development machine's localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it.
I discovered that the router were I'm connected is blocking the traffic.
I've tried both with another router and with my mobile service provider's network: connecting both my laptop and my device over the same network did part of the job.

I also  had to change configurations (run -> change configurations) and create a new backend configuration.

This backend's configuration need to have a Server address listening to the computer's IP address instead of the default "localhost". Apparently, only this way the client and backend addresses will match. 
Of course the http request needs to be over the same IP address where the backend is listening.

Comment: I'm glad.  It sound like an awful problem.

Comment: In these configuration settings, there is an option to sync with gradle.configuration. I assume that means there is a property you can add to your gradle file so that you can accept all incoming traffic and not just localhost. Do you know what the gradle configuration should look like by chance?

Comment: @DanielGeorge A bit late I guess, but I just ran into this same problem, so this may help others as well: I solved it by adding httpAddress = '0.0.0.0' into the appengine field of the backend's gradle config file, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591647/how-to-get-google-cloud-tools-for-android-studio-listen-on-all-ip-addresses). I don't know why, but I tried to change the backend's settings through the menu as the accepted answer said, but the server address's field was uneditable, at least in my version of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If the servlet is deployed to the google app engine you should be able to see the ip address information for it in the app engine console.  Are you deploying to the app engine or running the servlet locally to debug?

Either way, check to make sure you are making a post request. That's what the servlet is set up to listen for.

It's not so easy to make one from the browser.  You can try it using CURL, like this:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: I am running the servlet locally in Android Studio.

Comment: Ok I've deployed the module to the Google App Engine but I don't see any IP address in the console...where do you mean?

Comment: I don' have a java app running now, but follow the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/applicationsettings

Comment: Your curl request returns the html equivalent of the "Hello, App Engine" page, is that correct?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, if the endpoint was correctly called, you should see your expected toast result.